# Get Input text value programatically using id in ADF mobile

Tags: oracle-adf

I get Input Text value programatically using id in ADF mobile like ADF.

Below code is use in adf for get value for Input text programatically.

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
UIViewRoot root = facesContext.getViewRoot();
RichInputText inputText = (RichInputText)root.findComponent("it1");
String val=inputText.getValue();
```

But I can't get value like that in ADF mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the value from the page definition, instead of finding the component from the root.

```
DCIteratorBinding iterator = (DCIteratorBinding)dcBindings.get("SomeIteratorId"); 
String attribute = (String) iterator.getCurrentRow().getAttribute("SomeAttributeName");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the utility AdfmfJavaUtilitiy to get the value of ELs.
For example see https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/adf_mobile_update_through_web